# How to automatically segment multidimensional data?

Tags: time-series, non-parametric

How to partition the time-series multidimensional data in the figure below into segments using an unsupervised algorithm, so that the information within the same segment remains consistent, while the information in adjacent segments differs? Note that the algorithm should be adaptive because we do not know how many segments each time-series data should be divided into.[image][image][image]

The data can be found [here](https://github.com/qxdfd/data-segmentation).